# Do Sophos and Spotlight conflict and if so, how can I run both applications without problems?

Tags: battery, spotlight, performance, cpu

I just got a brand new 13" MacBook Pro at work.  I have noticed that Spotlight has been running constantly giving me ~4 hours of battery life.  The motivation for getting this laptop was to have the portability of an 8+ hour laptop.

Searching online, I saw indexing a directory that is synced by a service such as Dropbox/Syncthing would lead to excessive indexing.  To eliminate this as the source of the problem, I excluded from the Spotlight indexing the directories updated using sync services.  I even went so far as to exclude my entire home directory from Spotlight.  Yesterday I tried deleting the Spotlight index forcing it to re-index, and it has been running constantly for the last 24 hours without change.  The hard drive is 512 GB but only have 122 GB of data.

I now think the problem may be caused by Sophos, the required anti-virus software.  I have seen other posts commenting on these applications conflicting but the solutions recommend removing Sophos, not an option for me.  Are there settings that allow these applications to ignore each other?  Perhaps I need to have Spotlight ignore the Sophos files.  Where are the status files for Sophos stored?

**Edit:**
Here are the results of the command `mdutil -a -s` (I get the same result with/without `sudo`):

```
2016-04-18 00:36:53.470 mdutil[12692:72953] Metadata.framework [Error]: mdsCopyStorePaths failed: (268435459) (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Spotlight server is disabled.
```

I am not entirely sure what to make of this.  Viewing the system status using `htop`, the most demanding process is `/System/Library/CoreSerices/Spotlight.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotlight` using 112-160% of a CPU.

[This Apple thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6794027?tstart=0) recommends completely deleting the `/.Spotlight-V100/` directory and rebooting.  I tried this but it does not seem to do anything.  After rebooting, the folder was not recreated, Spotlight is still consuming a excessive system resources, and `mdutil` still reports the same thing (`I tried enabling the server using the command`mdutil -a -i on`but this produces the same output as`mdutil -a -s` shown above).

Comment: This just smacks of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Spotlight was busy indexing a new machine; so you kept changing what it should be indexing. Then when it was nearly finished you threw it out & made it start over. Then you assume another cause & ask about that instead.

Comment: I let it run for three days without trying to address the problem. Should I expect it to take more than 72 hours to index 122GB of data? I want a laptop with 8+ hours of battery life, but I'm getting 3-4. The energy stats say spotlight is consuming a significant amount of battery power.

Comment: 72 hours is a huge problem, this isn't `Spotlight`, this is a bad movie. I would estimate `Spotlight` to eat the CPU and the I/O for 2 to 3 hours but no more. Did you look at `Activity Monitor` to see if there isn't another problem going on?

Comment: @danielAzuelos, `Activity Monitor` shows several applications running but `Spotlight` is the only one using much CPU. The `Energy` tab shows `Spotlight` is the only application with energy impact above 1.

Comment: Do you have any form of access to a file server either on your local network or on the Internet? ---- Do you have any software update in progress (check `App Store`)? ----- Do you see anything else which might be harvesting your filesystem?

Comment: I do not have access to a file server. No updates have been running. Last night I disabled all apps I usually run, including sophos, wifi, and Bluetooth, then let Spotlight run all night (8+ hours) with no improvement.

Comment: Is this the 2nd time `Spotlight` make a >8 hours run? (Sorry, the concept of "last night" is much too vague).

Comment: Sorry @danielAzuelos, yes, I let it run a second time with everything else shot off but it did not make a difference.

Comment: Then you have a serious problem with `Spotlight` alone or something else. ---- I would suggest you to start another question targeting this problem and providing enough context info.

Comment: @danielAzuelos, It may be caused by a conflict with some other aspect of my work's monitoring/security software. I just created a new user, with no extra background applications, deleted everything in `/.Spotlight-V100` and I am going to let it index overnight. If it is still having problems in the morning, I may let the IT people re-image the machine. The IT people mentioned they had seen this happen after imaging the machine when using `Time Machine` to restore files (I did not do). They recommended some of the same things listed here and said if that didn't work they would re-image it.

Comment: Please, do an `mdutil -a -s` and incorporate this command and its output in your actual question. This also might help your IT colleague to understand the origin of this problem.

Comment: Have a look at this thread with a good answer to analyze the Spotlight nightmare: http://superuser.com/a/46381 .

Comment: Tha Apple discussion you quoted is unfortunately just a discussion. Not the smallest analysis to help understand. And with no understanding the hope for a solution is just… random.

Comment: It turned out that the monitoring software my work had on the computer contained a corrupt file that produced the never-ending Spotlight cycle.

Comment: Please, provide this information since it might be very helpfull to a lot of us. • I still very regularly hunt problems with `Spotlight` and I haven't yet been able to kill them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't conflict. `Spotlight` is a pig on any first run on a newly accessed filesystem. On the other hand, `Sophos` will double the load caused by controlling all these filesystem accesses.

I suggest you to let `Spotlight` terminate its heavy initial run alone
by temporarily turning off the `On-Access` control of `Sophos`:
[image: Sophos On-Access Off]

I also suggest you to turn off the scan on `Files on network volumes`, because this will load your Mac, your network and finally
your network volumes. On a well managed network, this scanning should be
run directly on the storage servers.

Once this 1st run terminated, `Spotlight` will less tend to be a CPU and I/O hog.

Comment: Spotlight has been running for 8 hours after shutting off Sophos and disconnecting the Internet. It is still consuming significant amount of CPU and energy.

Comment: This seems sufficient to resolve the question I asked.  They do not conflict, but it may be good to turn off Sophos during the initial indexing.  In my situation, it turned out that the system administrators had pushed out a corrupt file as part of their monitoring (maybe Sophos but maybe not) software.  As I got them involved, they eventually found the corrupt file and had to remotely login to remove it.